# Excel drop down list in a drop down list in a drop down list

Tags: worksheet-function

In excel I want a single cell drop down list that automatically progresses from manufacture, to model, then to part. An example would be first I click on a cell it would show four manufactures, when I move over a manufacture it would the show ten models, when I move over a model it would show fifty parts,I click on a part that and that part would be put in the cell I started in.
What I am trying to do is have a single cell in a invoice that through the above progression will put the part I need in as opposed to having all the parts from all the models from all the manufactures in one list.

Comment: The menu you're describing is called a "flyout menu." This doesn't exist in Excel by default but I'm sure there is an add-in that can do this. Are you familiar with adding Active-X controls to Excel spreadsheets (tools in the Developer tab)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is only possible to have one dropdown in a cell.

You could set up a multi-cell menu where the first cell has you choose a manufacturer, the second a model, and the third a part, where the options in the dropdown depends on the one before it.  You could then populate your final cell with the model chosen.

Another way would be to embed an IE web browser control, and code something with HTML and JS.